# Using FMOD for C#?

Tags: c#, fmod

I'm working with FMOD in C#. I've tried importing the `fmodex.dll` file by selecting Project->Add Reference and browsing for the `fmodex.dll`, but I am getting an error:

> A reference to ... could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component

It is accessible, but I still get the error. I read the guide and it says to use the `fmodex_vc.lib` when linking to the `fmodex.dll` file. So I try, but I can't seem to find on how to link to .lib files in Visual Studio; searching Google always leads me to linking to .dll files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fmod is written in unmanaged C++ so you cannot reference it directly from a .Net application. There is a c# wrapper to the fmodex.dll in the fmod package under a directory called "fmod_wrapper" if I am not mistaken that you can add to your project and which will take care of making the P/Invoking for you.

Comment: Yes, the C# wrapper is provided with the FMOD SDK to handle the P/Invoke. Just to clarify it is located in <install dir>\api\csharp

Answer (score 2):

Try https://github.com/madrang/FmodSharp been working for a little while on it. It should be better than the current Fmod wrapper.

Instead of using Handles and coding like you are using C++ in C#. The FmodSharp wrapper is object oriented and there is no need to think about using handles.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Fmod Play File Test");

    Xpod.FmodSharp.Debug.Level = Xpod.FmodSharp.DebugLevel.Error;
    var SoundSystem = new Xpod.FmodSharp.SoundSystem.SoundSystem();

    Console.WriteLine ("Default Output: {0}", SoundSystem.Output);

    SoundSystem.Init();
    SoundSystem.ReverbProperties = Xpod.FmodSharp.Reverb.Presets.Room;

    if (args.Length > 0) {
        foreach (string StringItem in args) {
            Xpod.FmodSharp.Sound.Sound SoundFile;
            SoundFile = SoundSystem.CreateSound (StringItem);

            Xpod.FmodSharp.Channel.Channel Chan;
            Chan = SoundSystem.PlaySound(SoundFile);

            while(Chan.IsPlaying) {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

            SoundFile.Dispose();
            Chan.Dispose();
        }

    } else {
        Console.WriteLine ("No File to play.");
    }

    SoundSystem.CloseSystem();
    SoundSystem.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Okay to get this to work I had to manually copy the fmodex.dll into the bin folder it creates after building in the root of the project.

Comment: Been a long time since i worked on this project. There are some of the more advanced features that are not implemented, if you need some of them, you can always help me by sending a commit after implementing them. When i have more free time i should send a few updates for this.
I hope it helps you develop your project.

Comment: they seem to have removed it.

Comment: Forgot to update the link. Now at https://github.com/madrang/FmodSharp
But i havent had the time to update it to work with the latest FMod version.
I should do that at some point.....

Answer (score 1):

In order to use FMOD in C# you need to wrap FMOD functions and structures using p/Invoke. This task has been taken care of for you in the open source project [fmodnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fmodnet/)

Comment: I believe the fmodnet project is quite out of date, I would recommend sticking to the C# wrapper provided with the FMOD SDK.

Comment: It's been a while since the last time I used it. So you are problably right and using the one provided with FMOD should be better.

Comment: It doesn't work either. Visual Studio reports it's missing the FMDOnet reference, and it's not in the downloaded zip file.

Comment: @Matthew Lock You do realize this answer is 3 years old... right?

Comment: Sure, but someone's got to say it doesn't work to help others.

Answer (score -1):

To add a COM item to a VS project perform the following steps:

- Register the COM
- Select "Add Reference"
- Select COM tab
- Browse to item and select it.

You should see (after a build) that VS has created an Interopt DLL library in your BIN dir.

Comment: @yms - as you say; the question implied he was trying to add a COM, I've no knowledge of FMOD specifically.